# Java file runs but not Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a jar file for one of my files (Worker.java). The file is in the beatDB package in the src/ folder.

To create the jar I ran `jar cfm InitializeInstanceWorker.jar Manifest.txt -C src/ .` and my Manifest.txt contains: `Main-Class: Main-Class: beatDB.Worker \n` with a new line at the end.

When I call `java beatDB/Worker` the file runs, but then when I try to run the jar file, java.lang.ClassDefNotFoundException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have `aws-java-sdk-1.7.7.jar` in my lib folder, which is on the classpath, which I set in my .bash_profile file.

Does anyone know why running the java file directly works, but the jar file does not run?

Comment: Have you tried packaging that external jar with your jar.

Comment: have you tried using eclipse to generate your runnable jar for you. That tends to work for me

Comment: @Harbinger How do you package the external jar with my jar?

Comment: @satnam I tried, but when I do export -> Runnable JAR file, my file doesn't appear.

Comment: Yep! Runnable Jar is an easiest way. Check whether you have any working sets created and looking in that.

Comment: in the export dialog, it lets you choose the location of the jar file. make sure you are looking in the right spot. Maybe export it to your desktop

Answer (score 0):

The ways that you can run your `jar/main class` are:

`java -cp InitializeInstanceWorker.jar;lib\aws-java-sdk-1.7.7.jar beatDB.Worker`

Or

java -cp lib\aws-java-sdk-1.7.7.jar beatDB.Worker -jar InitializeInstanceWorker.jar`

Or, if you add the attribute `Class-Path: lib/` in your jar, you will be able to run it by:

`java -jar InitializeInstanceWorker.jar`

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the help! I ended up just using eclipse to export a runnable jar.